# How to convert OOTB webpart to HTML for SPFX Environment in office 365 SharePoint

Tags: office-365

I have scenario in which we have made the most of the page into OOTB webpart in Office 365SharePoint.Right now UI doesn't  look as per client. Now they want to do convert into SPFX .Is that possible to convert the OOTB to HTML .So that it can fit into SPFX Environment. If not possible do i need to convert the page into HTML format?

Regards,
Mohamed

Comment: Are you moving from on-premise to SPO? OOTB webpart means the webpart come with SharePoint on-premise installation. SharePoint online should have already provided most of them.

Comment: I have used modern page in office 365.But now i want the same page to make it to spfx. Will i able to convert existing office 365 page to spfx?

Comment: I don't think so. First I don't think old webparts can be converted to "source code". Second spfx is using completely different programming approach. You can only build a new spfx webpart by copying the old design.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Please let me know the steps for the above question or else let me know can I use html code(Htmlpage) in spfx environment?

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want to do is not possible.

But I can understand why you may *think* that M365 will somehow ‘convert’ site pages to the Modern UX.

The modern User eXperience is applied to certain interfaces of SharePoint by default, even if the site is utilizing a ‘classic’ type template. e.g.: STS#1, STS#2, PUBLISHING#1, etc.

By default the *site contents* page and a couple of other interfaces are automatically ported to the Modern UX.  These pages are converted by the system, not you.  You will get no further assistance from Microsoft regarding site pages.  Especially if they are in a classic publishing site - the entire publishing model in SP has changed.

Deploying the modern SharePoint UX to an environment is not as simple as, for comparison purposes, a database upgrade from SP 2010 to 2013.  Or 2013 to 2016, etc.

It will be a far more involved process than you likely desire.  I can give you bullet points about how to do this successfully - and would be willing to post them if that is your next move.

Comment: Thank you Fritz. Please let me know the steps for the above question or else let me know can I use html code(Htmlpage) in spfx environment?